# Sqlite3 c# | How to only have

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

First here is my code: Bio

```
        ConnectionHandler databaseObject = new ConnectionHandler();
        databaseObject.OpenCnx();
        string writeData = $"INSERT INTO `{ctx.Member.Id}PROFILE` (`Bio`) VALUES (@Bio)";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(writeData, databaseObject.cnx);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bio", $"{BioMessage}");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        databaseObject.CloseCnx();
```

and now for the profile image

```
ConnectionHandler databaseObject = new ConnectionHandler();
        databaseObject.OpenCnx();
        string writeData = $"INSERT INTO `{ctx.Member.Id}PROFILE` (`ProfileImage`) VALUES (@ProfileImage)";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(writeData, databaseObject.cnx);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileImage", $"{url}");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        databaseObject.CloseCnx();
```

Once I have set them as in writing them into the sqlite3 database it creates 2 rows one for Bio but blank profile image field and the other has the URL to the image in profile image but have the bio field blank

[Data Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7EyP.png)

How would I go about putting both the bio and profile image on the same row?

Comment: You are doing two individual INSERT commands.  Your second SQL statement, if it needs to be seperate to add the image url, you will need an UPDATE command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two individual INSERT commands, hence the reason why your data is sitting in two individual rows.

You have two options:

1. Add the image url into your original INSERT command with your BIO.
2. If you need to add the Image URL separate, you will need to update your original row with the Image Url, by means of an update command, as follow:

   ```
   ConnectionHandler databaseObject = new ConnectionHandler();
   databaseObject.OpenCnx();
   string writeData = $"UPDATE `{ctx.Member.Id}PROFILE` SET ProfileImage = @ProfileImage WHERE YOurIDColumnName = IDOfRowYouWantToUpdate";
   SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(writeData, databaseObject.cnx);

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileImage", $"{url}");
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   databaseObject.CloseCnx();
   ```

Please take Note of the following in the UPDATE command:

```
 WHERE YOurIDColumnName = IDOfRowYouWantToUpdate
```

This is your where condition, and you need to specify the Unique Identifier of the row you want to update here.  Without the WHERE clause, you will update and override each ProfileImage column in the table.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm) you will be able to find the syntax for an UPDATE query

Comment: @TheRealSpacebarButton Mind that you need to keep the order now. If you have Operation A do an insert and Operation B do the update, they always have to be executed in the order A, B. If you cannot ensure this, you need to make them both "UPSERT"s (i.e. UPDATE if entry exists, else INSERT)